# nodejs how to do multiple requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i need to know how i can write my request to make multiple delete.
the second thing is how can i put async function on my code.
i want to delete a campus and in the same time dele the builings with the same id campus in the JSON

```
app.delete('/campuses/:id', (req, res)=> {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const details = { 'campusid': new ObjectID(id) };  
    db.db('').collection('buildings').remove(details, (err, result)=> { 
        if (err) {
            res.send({ 'error': 'en error has occured' });
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
    const details2 = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
    db.db('').collection('campuses').remove(details2, (err, result)=> { 
        if (err) {
            res.send({ 'error': 'en error has occured' });
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    }
    );
})
```

Comment: try using Promises or async lib
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete like this.

```
app.delete('/campuses/:id', async (req, res)=> {
 try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const details = { 'campusid': new ObjectID(id) };  
    await db.db('').collection('buildings').remove(details);
    const details2 = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
    await db.db('').collection('campuses').remove();
    res.send(result);
  } catch(err) {
   return res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'error'
            });
  }
})
```

Comment: thanks you! that was vers helpful can you just explain how the return **res.json** success,message works?

Answer (score 0):

You could make sequential functions where the first one calls the second one. You could then pass on variables to the seconds function (ie. your campus ID).

It could look something like this:

```
    const Query1 = (res, query) => {
        const request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(query, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'error'
                });
            } else if (result.recordset[0]) {

                let campusID = result.recordset;

                Query2(res, campusID, query = 'SELECT bla bla')

            }
        })
    }

    const Query2 = (res, campusID, query) => {
        const request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(query, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'error'
                });
            } else {

                return res.json({
                    success: true
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to make async call.

1. You can use promises.
2. Async Functions.
3. Sending response without waiting for other tasks.
4. If you want to make parallel calls you can use [bluebird join](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) function

Comment: my internship master told me that i have to use promises and async functions. i'm reading the different libraries to make it

Comment: Core promises are the best way to make calls. But if you want to want to use more facilities over default promises you can use an async library. For parallel processing I prefer bluebird. They claim their promises are even faster than the core node.

Answer (score 0):

I like the syntax of async functions better than promises, but I use both depending on the situation.

Here is an example of running functions in order before moving to the next function:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback1) {
        //Do some work, then callback
        if (error) {
            callback1(errorGoesHere,null);
        } else {
            callback1(null,successMessageGoesHere);
        }

    }, 
    function(callback2) {
        //Do some work, then callback
        if (error) {
            callback2(errorGoesHere,null);
        } else {
            callback2(null,successMessageGoesHere);
        }
    }
], function (error, success) {
    if (error) { 
        //show an error 
    }
    //all good return the response, etc.
});
```

If anything in these functions fail, it automatically call the end function to catch the error.